# Оформление цитат, встроенных в текст

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно оформить следующее предложение?

Хочу повторить то, что сказал В. И. Ленин: «Учиться, учиться и еще раз учиться» настоящим образом.

Может быть: Хочу повторить то, что сказал В. И. Ленин: «Учиться, учиться и еще раз учиться». Настоящим образом.

Comment: Цитата неверна. Ленин писал: «учиться, учиться и учиться». См. Википедию: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B

Comment: Странно построена эта фраза. Если хотите **повторить** то, что сказал В. И. Ленин, то зачем заканчивать его фразу вашими словами?

Comment: Здесь смешаны две цитаты Ленина: "Учиться, учиться и учитьcя...", - и: "Учиться военному делу настоящим образом".

Answer (score 2):

*Известные слова Ленина **«учиться, учиться и учиться»** были написаны им в работе «Попятное направление русской социал-демократии»...*
(Кстати, вот она — цитата, встроенная в текст.)
По правилам она должна быть ограничена двумя троеточиями: «...учиться, учиться и учиться...» — как ***часть*** предложения. Но фраза стала крылатым выражением, "живет своей известной жизнью", вполне самодостаточна, поэтому троеточий нет.

***Если предложение не заканчивается цитатой, то после нее ставят запятую*** (если цитата входит в состав деепричастного оборота или завершает первую часть сложного предложения) ***или тире*** (если цитата заканчивается многоточием, восклицательным или вопросительным знаком, а также если по условиям контекста отделять последующий текст запятой не нужно).
[**Знаки препинания при цитировании (как прямая речь)**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-rubric-76)

Ваши предложения могли бы иметь такой вид:

**Хочу повторить ленинские слова «учиться, учиться и учиться» и добавить: учиться настоящим образом.**
Или:
**Хочу повторить слова В. И. Ленина: «Учиться, учиться и учиться» — и добавить, что учиться надо настоящим образом.**
Или:
**Хочу повторить то, что сказал В. И. Ленин: «Учиться, учиться и учиться», и добавить, что учиться надо настоящим образом.**

Comment: Помнится мне, что "настоящим образом" - тоже цитата из Ленина (попробую найти), их часто соединяют в одно целое.

Comment: Ленин: Наш лозунг должен быть один — учиться военному делу настоящим образом, ввести порядок на железных дорогах. — Политический отчёт ЦК VII съезду РКП(б), 7 марта 1918 г.— ПСС, 36-е изд., стр. 26 т. 36, с. 26.

Comment: Хорошо! - это ведь не МОЙ вопрос двухлетней давности. Можно и поменять ПО СМЫСЛУ  в предложении: всерьёз, как следует,  должным образом...  Извините,  но пунктуация от этого - не изменится!  Хочу повторить ленинские слова «учиться, учиться и учиться» и добавить: учиться должным  образом... Известные слова Ленина «учиться, учиться и учиться» были написаны им в работе «Попятное направление русской социал-демократии», написанной в конце 1899 и опубликованной в 1924 году в журнале «Пролетарская революция»

Comment: @М_Г Мы будем искать историческую правду или - пунктуационную? НЕ соединяют ИХ в одно целое: века разные... Я неправильно сделала "оформление цитат, встроенных в текст"?

Comment: @М_Г Вы противоречите самому себе, смотрите ВАШ комментарий: " 
Странно построена эта фраза. Если хотите повторить то, что сказал В. И. Ленин, то зачем заканчивать его фразу вашими словами? – М_Г 5 фев в 13:30."

Comment: Римма, я написал мой последний комментарий только "для справки" и поэтому не мог противоречить самому себе. И нет в нем критики в ваш адрес. Я помню эти лозунги еще со школьных времен, две цитаты были объединены в одну фразу. Но это неправильно, фактически подтасовка. А ваши варианты лучше, чем тот, что в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

А что Вас именно интересует - какой знак препинания должен стоять после "учиться"? У Вас вместо знаков препинания после слова "учиться" стоят какие-то символы. Пожалуйста, исправьте. Тогда и легче будет ответить. Пока могу лишь сказать: после слова "учиться" поставьте тот знак препинания, который указан в цитате. Вносить изменения в цитату не следует.

Comment: У вас, видимо, неверно отображается... В исходном варианте после цитаты "учиться, учиться и еще раз учиться" предложение продолжается словами "настоящим образом". Я не знала, как в таком случае поступить с кавычками: надо ли закавычивать все или только цитату и правильно ли давать ее с большой буквы? Мой вариант - разбить на два предложения, но как поступить, если не разбивать?